# Angular4 private or public method?

Tags: angular, oop, typescript

some clarification needed. I have an simple Angular 4 component with a button there.
I have a method in component `handleButtonClick` and I bind it to button `(click)` event.

Is `handleButtonClick` method considered as private or public?

Comment: `handleButtonClick ` function is Public

Answer (score 3):

The default type for function is Public in typescript

See : https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html

Answer (score 2):

> private or public method?

#### What is Public methods?

Any function that is accessible outside using an instance of a class is public. This is the default access specifier.

#### What is Private methods?

Any function that is required for internal purpose should be private. This function will not be accessible outside class. Even instances of this class will not have access to these function. If you try to access these function outside class, they will throw error.

So considering above explanation, it is *public*.

Comment: Thanks, I see the difference between public and private. But I don't know exactly if using method within Angular's component template means that it is external using or internal. So it turned to be external.

Comment: By external use, if an instance of this class/component can access this method, it is public

Answer (score 0):

Your method must be public in case you make any **AOT** compilations this will throw an error:

*method can't be accessed because this is private or protected.*

This is just a convention used to have more **OOP** oriented structure. Remember that in JS there is no **private** or **protected** object members.